# Does iOS contain database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

I am wondering if iOS has any build-in database, and if so - maybe you can direct me to some tutorials and/or API-description online ( similare to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) ).

I am new to *iOS and Objective-C* programming. I have experience with Java and Android-development, and I am currently developing an Android-application for containing what CD's I have in my possession / collection - and want to re-produce it to iOS.
   I have gotten stuck at the point at where I'm not sure how to save the information for the iOS-application. In Android you have an built-in database that you can use, and I stumbled upon an input ( here on StackOverflow ) a while back that someone wrote something about an SQLite-database and I would like to create an database first-time the application is run.

The alternative would be to save an file ( XML or JSON ) containing the information. But as the application is meant to handle large sums of information I want to use an database of some sort.

Thanks for all the possible help and directions to where I can find more information.

Comment: SO isn't really the place to start looking for these things. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what you should ask. But to answer your question, yes. See what [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS has [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) that works great in most of the cases. If you are used to Android's SQLite you can also [use SQLite in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app). Although, in general, people use Core Data.

XCode provides you a set of tools to work with Core Data. You can create a model inside XCode and see the relationship between Entities. [Core data is not a relational database](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html). It can be persisted in a relational database (SQLite) but the concept that supports Core Data is different.  Core data is "an object graph manager with lifecycle" and you shouldn't fight against that concept. Try to understand the differences before dive into Core Data.

[Dylan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887118/dylan-crocker) touched an important part. You also have wrappers and tools to help you with SQLite. One of them is [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb?source=cc).

For CoreData you also have a framework that can help you called [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).

Comment: If you use SQLite I recommend this wrapper (It will save you tons of time!): https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb?source=cc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS come with built in [core data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) feature. Here is the [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial) you can start with.